# Android dispatchKeyEvent trigger onclick event

Tags: android, events

A `TextView` contains two events including `dispatchKeyEvent` and `onclick` event. When I click the enter key, the `onclickevent` was also touched off, I don't know how to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).